# Do all fungi dislike acidic environments?

Tags: mycology

I know that some fungi prefer mildly alkaline environments and dislike acidic environments. Is that true of all fungi, or do some fungi prefer acidic environments? If so, are such acidic fungi rare exceptions or is it common for there to be acid-loving fungi?

Comment: Many fungi prefer acidic environment. Such as most skin-disease causing fungi prefer acidic environment. (However this does not mean they'll be cured at alkaline environment)

Comment: To add to @AlwaysConfused's comment, the skin has naturally an acidic pH at around 5.5 http://skincarerx.com/article-ph

Answer (score 3):

Fungi that grow in acidic media are well known, here just one reference: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC518635/pdf/jbacter00651-0183.pdf

About their spread, they are less common in mild environments (like you hands, or your garden soil) but of course in acidic environments, they will be predominant.